# clearInterval is not destroying setInterval timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I'm creating an image rotator that cycles through two images with a nice crossfade. I'm using `setInterval` to do it - but for performance reasons, I'd like to stop the timer while the browser is being resized.

First I define the function and global handler:

```
var imageRotator;
var getImageRotator = function() {
    if (imageRotator)
        clearInterval(imageRotator); // <-- not working it would seem?
    setInterval(function() {
        $('.imageRotator').animate({opacity: ($('.imageRotator').css("opacity") == 1) ? 0 : 1}, 500);
    }, 9000);
};
```

Then in both `$(document).ready()` and `$(window).smartResize()` I do:

```
imageRotator = getImageRotator();
```

It starts it up OK at 9s intervals, but every time I resize the browser, it adds a new timer and it starts crossfading rather incessantly.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are no returning from the getimageRotatorFunction()

```
var imageRotator;
var getImageRotator = function() {
    if (imageRotator)
        clearInterval(imageRotator); // <-- not working it would seem?
    return setInterval(function() {
        $('.imageRotator').animate({opacity: ($('.imageRotator').css("opacity") == 1) ? 0 : 1}, 500);
    }, 9000);
};
```

Now you can simply do this

```
imageRotator = getImageRotator();
```

Comment: why is there a downvote? im sure this solves the purpose

Comment: No idea.. it certainly does

Comment: then plus one for you then (:

Comment: @remus Just a reminder, if an answer helps you, you can click on the tick beside the answer to help other visitors determine the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: Yes @mauris ;) but not until the grace period has ended.

Answer (score 1):

If you did `imageRotator = getImageRotator();`, you then need to return the timer from the `getImageRotator` function. The `return` statement is missing on the `setInterval` method:

```
var imageRotator;
var getImageRotator = function() {
    if (imageRotator) {
        clearInterval(imageRotator); // <-- not working it would seem?
        return setInterval(function() {
            $('.imageRotator').animate({opacity: ($('.imageRotator').css("opacity") == 1) ? 0 : 1}, 500);
        }, 9000);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually clearing the interval.

you need to actually set a imageRotatorInterval and then clear that. Something like the following:

```
var imageRotator;
var imageRotatorInterval;
var getImageRotator = function() {
    if (imageRotator)
        clearInterval(imageRotatorInterval); 
    imageRotatorInterval = setInterval(function() {
        $('.imageRotator').animate({opacity: ($('.imageRotator').css("opacity") == 1) ? 0 : 1}, 500);
    }, 9000);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to id assign.
Let simple return and use it:

```
var getImageRotator = function() {
    if (imageRotator)
        clearInterval(imageRotator); // <-- not working it would seem?
    return setInterval(function() {
        $('.imageRotator').animate({opacity: ($('.imageRotator').css("opacity") == 1) ? 0 : 1}, 500);
    }, 9000);
};
var imageRotator = getImageRotator();
```